# How to create "array of arrays of objects" schema in Mongoose.js

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I need to create schema for following data structure:

```
{
  ...
  matrix: [
    [{type: "A", count: 6}, {type: "B", count: 4}],
    [{type: "B", count: 1}, {type: "A", count: 2}, {type: "A", count: 1}],
    [{type: "C", count: 7}, {type: "A", count: 1}],
  ]
}
```

I tried to do so like this while defining my schema, but it caused validation errors:

```
const cellSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  type: String,
  count: Number
});

const matrixSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ...
  matrix: [[cellSchema]]
});
```

it seems that such a schema syntax is supported now in Mongoose (https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1361).

Comment: Using `matrix: [[]]` solves the problem. But what about defining schema for `cellSchema` ?

Answer (score 4):

Sample code to create Array of arrays of object:

```
const cellSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    type: String,
    count: Number
});

const matrixSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    matrix: [[cellSchema]]
});

const Matrix = mongoose.model('Matrix', matrixSchema);

const newMatrix = new Matrix({
    matrix: [
        [{ type: 'xyz', count: 10 }, { type: 'ABC', count: 20 }],
        [{ type: 'pqr', count: 10 }]]
});
newMatrix.save();
```

[**Output**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAEi6.png)
[image]