# Indexing items in array - MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm quite new to `mongodb`, hence I would like to know how the mongoose schema should look like when I need to add indexed items in an array.

Here is how I want the output to look like:

```js
_id: some_id
users: Object
  0: Array
      0: some_user_id
      1: some_user_id
      2: some_user_id
```

This is the schema I tried to create, but I think I'm wrong here:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const timerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  users: [[]]
})

module.exports = timerSchema
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi there! To clarify, do you want the `timerSchema.users` property to hold an array of arrays?

Comment: @Tunmee thanks for getting to me!
Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `timerSchema.users` property to hold an array of arrays then your schema definition is correct.you can also specify type of array, refer [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52944240/how-to-create-array-of-arrays-of-objects-schema-in-mongoose-js/62585867#62585867) example to create array of arrays using mongoose Schema which contain output as well.

or if you want users as object then,

```
const timerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  users: {
         <Field1>:[[]],
         <Field2>:<Type>
      }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! You helped me a lot.